# How to get lib for painting function graph on .net 3.5 and lower

Tags: c#, .net, charts, visualization

I have problem how to find some lib which can make function graph  for .net 3.5 and lower. I already use **.net chart** and **ZedGraph**. But i use it for  .net 4.5. What alternatives exist for older versions of the .net framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20source/ and downloading the source, I just compiled the 5.1.5 version for .NET 2.0. Either compile it yourself or download at https://ufile.io/zm43k. Hope this solves your problem.